# How do Grand Prix Ranking work?

Tags: mario-kart-7

I've noticed that the star ranking system for the cups on Mario Kart 7 will sometimes seem random.

Sometimes, when I beat a cup with a score of 40, it will give me only 2 stars and sometimes it will give me 3.  Furthermore, when I beat a cup with a score in between 32 and 38, I will usually get 1 star, but sometimes I get 2.

I've read on some sites that your rank after each cup is based on lap time, number of faults, lead time after a lap, coins collected, time in the off-road, etcetera.

How does it actually work? Is there a definitive answer?

Comment: personally i think the "time spent off road" and "number of faults" things are totally bogus speculations, since every good shortcut in the game requires time spent off road, or abusing the fault system, and using those shortcuts is more likely to get you the 3 stars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Mario Kart Wii, there is no definitive answer, as the game developers have not released this information. Star ranking appears to correlate the most with fast track times and good coin collection (though that may be because coins make you faster), but nothing out there is definitive.

It is certainly not random, however. Many players report getting 3 Stars on virtually all grand prix races every time they try them.